# Why was I moderator-suspended from chat for 24 hours?

Tags: support, chat, banning

I was suddenly banned from Stack Overflow chat by a moderator for 24 hours and I'm not sure why... I don't think I said anything offensive recently in the three rooms I'm in.

Could a moderator (ideally the one who suspended me) explain why?

I suspect the ban came down in the Documentation Beta chatroom:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta

but unlike some others, I was not handing out untoward criticism of Docs. Throughout the Public Beta of Docs I've actually been pretty supportive of it in chat, and I'm sure multiple folks with diamonds could attest to that.

I was even in the process of [helping someone](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31937093#31937093) who now is probably thinking I abandoned them.

---

The suspension seems to have been lifted after about 15 minutes.

Comment: Looks like quite a few people who were criticising docs got suspended. I know of at least 3 others.

Comment: I don't typically have drama here at my workplace, so thanks for giving attention to my usual Meta-supplement.

Comment: Are you sure?  Your link to "the perfect description of SO staff and Docs" might not necessarily be taken in stride.  I could repeat the link but who knows what might happen next :)

Comment: @HansPassant The comic that's often used to describe a feature or product having lots of bugs is now offensive and suspension worthy *without warning*? That's news to me. Not to mention it was posted quite some time before the ban with several moderators/staff in chat at the time who did nothing/did not object to it. Anyway that was in direct response to Undo anyway, and was a continuation of my previous line made in jest.

Comment: Were you on the anti-Docs team?  That might have been the reason since that is not what teams are for.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure what the anti-Docs team is, so I guess not?

Comment: The anti docs team was my idea as a joke. You've suspended others, I'd prefer it if you suspend me too.

Comment: @TylerH Good guess ;).  Not sure what you could have done to get suspended.  Hopefully someone will say something so we know what unwritten rule needs to be observed.

Comment: This appears to be the source: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31937109#31937109

Comment: Except that TylerH wasn't saying anything that could be remotely construed as negative in that discussion.  If anything he critiqued the allusion to "free speech infringement".

Comment: @BradLarson: I'm not really sure why that's worth a suspension. It's nothing that hasn't been said dozens of times on Meta.SO.

Comment: @JRichardSnape so did I... yet I was also banned. Note to self, don't try to defend SE in chat.

Comment: @BradLarson Wow, if that's the case, then I'm very concerned about that moderation activity. My line was not shade at all, it wasn't even satirical. Some normal user commented "Docs is SO's, it's their money. If we leave, no one will notice/care" and I simply responded "actually it's the VC's money :-P" If that is really what got me suspended, I think that's totally unreasonable and the suspending staffer should have looked at the context more carefully.

Comment: It also appears that [the ban did not originate with SO mods](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31937664#31937664) (presumably employees)?

Comment: For the record, it appears that some (not sure about all?) people have been unbanned.

Comment: @Servy they were timed for 24 hours, so they were manually lifted/removed.

Comment: Or reduced to 15 minutes (albeit effectively the same as manually lifting).

Comment: If you think Documentation is like this http://i.imgur.com/c4jt321.png you might want to leave the gasoline at home?  I dunno, just a thought...  That's why I'm staying far from it right now :)

Comment: @Ffisegydd I'm not sure they can easily change an existing ban duration. They'd probably have to lift the existing one and replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Will see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329660/why-was-i-moderator-suspended-from-chat-for-24-hours#comment373618_329660 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329660/why-was-i-moderator-suspended-from-chat-for-24-hours#comment373625_329660 for why that image isn't relevant here

Comment: @TylerH Nope, in fact that second link suggests the staff is getting a bit frustrated with the beating they're taking over it, and would be a bit sensitive and more likely to hand out bans like Oprah hands out cars.  But that's just my reading.

Comment: Also, shouldn't these bans that are being handed out *only* apply to the Documentation chat?

Comment: @cybermonkey I would think so, but AFAIK they were all 24-hour bans, so they'll be expiring in an hour.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The launch of Documentation brought out something that's as hard to articulate as it is to absorb, *how people feel*. Some people are really good at expressing their feelings in a constructive way, others just kinda let the raw feelings out, which often comes in the form of unactionable hostility.

We've seen a bit of the latter, and when that comes in *waves* directed at a single person all at once, it's sometimes hard to see what's actually benign and possibly helpful. When a lot of folks descend on someone in that manner, well, people react.

Your suspension has been lifted because you're pretty clearly not in the category of "I'm here just to derail things, and nothing you could say would change my mind" - something we've been struggling with in a culture that encourages people to speak openly and honestly. But openly and honestly is also fodder for trolls who just want to make people mad. It's hard to distinguish between those categories in real time.

#### We're sorry about that.

If you have actional feedback, including "*shut the whole damn thing down!*" - please bring it here so it (1) won't be missed as we go through transcripts and (2) so folks can prepare to engage with it. When many people are directing this kind of thing at *one* person, well - they overload and can't possibly give you anything useful in return.

Everyone that's here really *cares* about Stack Overflow, and we're all human, including almost everyone that works here (I think we have a few robots doing stuff).

If you feel really passionate about something, *come here*. If you have questions about how something works, or want to help others that have questions, you're more than welcome in chat.

Comment: *This* is the kind of response that I think many of us would have preferred to see on other topics Re: documentation :P

Comment: In the same time, I'm always wondering on the need to be passionate about docs ... :p

Comment: *shut the whole damn thing down!*

Comment: As one of the people who has *serious* misgivings about Documentation (though trying to stay open-minded and as constructive as possible), seeing reports of someone being banned for speaking their mind and sharing their opinion is *extremely* frightening. It kind of feeds into the impression I've gotten from team members over the past week that they are remarkably sensitive about this new feature, for unknown reasons, and would prefer to wave away criticism than actually deal with it. Even if this was an isolated case of real hostility, that doesn't change the very bitter taste it leaves...

Comment: This long answer could really sum up to: "*People have become overly critical of the documentation and in response we've become overly defensive. Sorry about that.*"

Comment: So has any action actually been taken about this? It sounds like you're apologizing, but not actually reprimanding whoever did it.

Comment: @CodyGray I suspect the sensitivity comes from various sources. Firstly the amount of work and time they put into docs coupled with some of the overly, shall we say, zealous criticism. Regardless whether you agree with docs or not, being downright unpleasant and nasty is no way to get SO to take criticism seriously. As for this specific incident, it appears to me that TylerH got caught in some crossfire, but some of the other bans were probably justified. Overall, one positive thing that this proves is just how passionate many people are about SO.

Comment: @David I was going to point out that I understand developing and launching any new product is a difficult and draining process, but I ran out of room. That recognition, however, does not change the fact that it never behooves developers to become overly attached to their work. And it never behooves anyone to become averse to criticism. Microsoft thought it was a really great idea to remove the Start menu from Windows. About 95% of Windows users disagreed with them, and kicked up a big stink. Rather than banning people, they capitulated and fixed the problem in a point-1 release.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, you're right, but the converse of that is to not allow passion to slip from the devs either. Is it worse to care too much about your work or to not care at all? It's all about the balance. the main crux for me is some of the vitriol thrown by a fairly small set of users. Regardless of how much you care about your code, that kind of stuff is always going to cause friction. As for the Windows start button, let us now forget that it took MS almost a year to capitulate on that, I'm fairly confident that it won't take that long here :)

Comment: The problem may simply be that I do not participate in chat. (And this kind of thing may, in fact, be part of the reason.) But I haven't seen any abusive vitriol here on Meta. I *have* seen lots of heated and intense criticism—from myself, Nicol Bolas, bwoebi, Gordon, and a number of others. Everything I've seen has been equally as constructive as it has been harsh. Earlier today, I saw Shog9 accuse Nicol Bolas of "ranting" about Docs. I think that's very much unfair and an overly defensive attitude. Nicol's criticism has been poignant but well-reasoned. And largely ignored. (cc @David)

Comment: @CodyGray I have seen some fairly bad stuff on meta recently, but most of it gets deleted. I've stayed out of chat for the same reason, popped my head in and saw how some people were talking and left pretty quickly! I saw Shog9's post about the ranting and I can see both sides here. There have been a number of very vocal people in meta, but I don't think it's helpful to name them.